# Prove that the number of vectors in LI subset can not exceed the number of vectors in a generating set of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, independence

Any subset 'T' of vector space is the generating set of vector space if every elements of vector space can be expressed as the linear combination of elements of 'T'.

Let S be the LI subset of vector space containing 'm' elements and T be the generating set of vector space containing 'n' elements then how to prove that 'm' can not exceed 'n' or 'm' is always less than or equal to 'n'.

Is it true that;If 'T' generates vector space then adding those elements of vector space to T,which is not in T also generates the vector space??
Is it true that adding the elements to generating set of vector space which is not in generating set makes the new set linearly dependent??

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ spans $V$, then it has a set of maximally LI elements (= basis for $V$). Therefore, for any other set $S$ of LI elements, $\vert S \vert \leq \vert V \vert$.

If $T$ spans $V$ then any other $S$ containing $T$ also spans $V$.

Comment: How can I prove the last line??

Comment: Please elaborate the answer??